# How do I know what type of document handleOpenURL is responding to?

Tags: ios

Let's say I have registered several schemes as appropriate for my app, such as text file and PDF.

I open an attached file in the mail app. My app is invoked, and the handleOpenURL method is fired with an URL.

Do I have to (crudely) parse the URL, or.. what?

Comment: `NSURL` has accessor methods such as `scheme`, `pathExtension`, ... . Is that what you call "crudely parsing"? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Yes. I register my app for (for example) file type public.rtf which is pretty specific, yet - at least on a Mac - a file may very well be known to be an RTF file, but not have the file extension .rtf

Comment: OK, now I see what you mean. Did you try `getResourceValue:forKey:error:` with the `NSURLTypeIdentifierKey`?

Comment: Nope, never used that one. Looking at it now.

Comment: Got it. Martin, why don't you pose that as an answer, so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `NSURL` method  `getResourceValue:forKey:error:` with the `NSURLTypeIdentifierKey`
to get the uniform type identifier (UTI) of the file passed to the application.

Comment: And here's the source snippet: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSString *type;
    NSError *error;
    if (![url getResourceValue:&type forKey:NSURLTypeIdentifierKey error:&error]) {
        return NO;
    }

Answer (score 1):

It isn't that hard to get at important bits of the URL (via [NSURL's pathExtension](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/pathExtension), for example, you might know what kind of .doc or .pdf or .txt file you're trying to open)

Comment: Well yes, but depending on the file extension - especially if the sending program knows - would kinda... I dunno... suck, wouldn't it?

Comment: The only thing the sending program is sending you is a URL which has a scheme and a document name (and of course potentially some other stuff between the scheme and the filename), but the sending program isn't sending you a MIME type.  You have to look at the filename that you're sent to figure out if there's a good hint as to what kind of file it is, and if that doesn't work you need to go inspect the file and figure out what kind of file it is yourself.  [If the file doesn't exist, you get to return a 404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404).